# i'm getting auth token response for linkedin in postman but don't know how to convert it into axios

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios, postman, linkedin-api

**i want to get post request response from axios if I  have token code I'm able to do that in postman but not able to complete it in axios**

**here is the postman response and all the require data I have to pass in postman [image]**

> what I did to get the response in react

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (code) {
      let configData = {
        client_id: 'hjhdjd',
        client_secret: 'e637833ndd',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/linkedin/callback',
        code: code,
      };

      console.log(configData);
       axios(
         configData
       )
         .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.results.bindings);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }, [code]);
```

**but after doing this I'm getting error given below**

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')

Answer (score 1):

You must call methods of axios, in this case you should use post:

```
axios.post(url,configData).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.results.bindings);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```